# не могу установить pip: "cannot import name 'PackageFinder' from 'pip._internal.index'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

На команду: `py -m pip install -U pip`

Выдает:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands import (
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands.completion import CompletionCommand
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\completion.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.base_command import Command
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index import PackageFinder
ImportError: cannot import name 'PackageFinder' from 'pip._internal.index' (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\__init__.py)
```

как установить pip?
помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: а зачем его надо устанавливать? Разве его не было сразу при установке питона? Попробуйте ввести команду `pip -V`. Что она выводит?

Comment: "pip" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: пишу после этого py -m pip install -U pip , а оно выдает  cannot import name 'PackageFinder' from 'pip._internal.index' (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\__init__.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в pip

Попробуйте [сделать так](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7620#issuecomment-576655739), чтобы поставить старшую, стабильную версию:

```
python get-pip.py pip==19.3.1
```

Comment: да, спасибо, оно установило пип 19 версии

Comment: но, когда хочу установить библиотеку numpy пишет "pip" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом

Comment: помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: @кля, похоже, в переменной окружения PATH нет папки с библиотеками питона, раз в консоли `pip` не нашли. Тогда, вызовите pip через питон: `python -m pip install numpy`

Comment: выдает на python -m pip install numpy    ImportError: cannot import name 'PackageFinder' from 'pip._internal.index' (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\__init__.py)

Comment: я уже все сайты перерыл, не знаю что делать

Comment: Покажите версию `python -m pip -V`, у меня, например, это вывело: `pip 19.1.1 from C:\Users\...`

Comment: вывело - pip 19.3.1

Comment: Странно, у меня таких проблем нет: поставил pip 19.3.1, переустановка numpy была успешной. У меня закончились идеи, попробуйте поставить python версии 3.7

Comment: блин, СРАБОТАЛО, спасибо большое

Comment: @кля, хорошо, что это помогло :) Жаль, что с новыми версиями такое происходит :(